# Total en una vista de Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

Quiero saber cual es el valor de la suma total de todas los registros que tengo del valor que estan dentro del for, que fueron obtenidos de la formula y que sea mostrado mostrado abajo de la tabla cuando`<td>${{number_format((($cuenta->interes / 100) * $transaccion->Cantidad)+ $transaccion->Cantidad,2)}}</td>`

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <h3>Comprobantes</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Cantidad</th>
                  <th>Descripcion</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                  <th>Interes</th>
                  <th>Balance</th>
                  <th>Quitar</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <body>
                @foreach ($transacciones as $transaccion)
                  @if ($transaccion->cuenta_id == $cuenta->id)
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{$transaccion->Cantidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$transaccion->descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$transaccion->created_at}}</td>
                    <td>${{number_format(($cuenta->interes / 100) * $transaccion->Cantidad)}}</td>
                    <td>${{number_format((($cuenta->interes / 100) * $transaccion->Cantidad)+ $transaccion->Cantidad,2)}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('transaccion-delete', $transaccion->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</td>
                    </tr>
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </body>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: Intenta con una consulta donde el campo interes le agregues el resultado de tu formula, lo comparas y el resultado de tu consulta lo cuentas con "count()" luego lo mandas a la vista, realiza todo eso desde el controlador para que tu HTML no sea extenso.

Comment: La suma total de qué necesitas? Veo que estás haciendo un foreach sobre $transacciones (posiblemente una colección), pero no me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr. Podrías explicarlo de otra manera?

Comment: ya lo solucione de otra manera solo usando php desde el blade